# Android:back event for WebView in a tabbed application in Appcelerator

Tags: android, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I can't find a way to capture android:back event with a tab window or a WebView in that tab.

I have a tabbed application, with a TabGroup acting as a root window. One of the tabs contains a WebView showing a blog.

To implement navigation on Android, I tried having event listeners for 'android:back' on the webview itself and on the Ti.UI.currentWindow, but it seems to have no effect. The application is closed when back button is pressed.

Meanwhile, [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) suggests it should be possible to receive keyDown with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK in a WebView.

Comment: Are none of these answers correct?

Answer (score 0):

Does your window have `exitOnClose: false`?

From the Ti.UI.window object documentation:

"(Android only.) Boolean indicates if the application should exit when the Android back button is pressed while the window is being shown. You can only set this as a createWindow({...}) option. Setting it after window creation will no effect."

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me ever since 1.5 when they released support for android:back event:

```
Ti.UI.currentWindow.addEventListener('android:back', function() { 
//do something 
});
```

Comment: Reading the docs the code you show should work.  It doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && (secondary_layout_is_displayed))
    {
        PrimaryLayout();
        // return true to let the system know we consumed the back button press
        return true;
    }

    // return the default value
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I'm using Titanium Appcelerator. Unfortunately, it does not cross-compile JavaScript source into Java and runs it in a VM of sort instead.